# Use locally Computer Modern Dunhill

Tags: fonts, computer-modern, roman

In the [documentation](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/computermoderndunhillroman/) of Computer Modern Dunhill, it’s only presented the way of using Dunhill in the whole document.

When my goal it’s just to use it in a peace of document. But when I do `{\setromanfont{cmdh} Lispsum}` I get :

```latex
! Package fontspec Error: The font "cmdh" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.133     {\setromanfont{cmdh}lipsum
                               }
```

So, how to use Computer Modern Dunhill in just a part of document and not in the whole document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provided no example and did not mention it but the error indicates you are using a Unicode engine so you should not be using the `cmdh` name which is only set up for 8 bit. However Latin Modern is set up, so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

Aabcd {\fontfamily{lmdh}\selectfont Abcd}

\end{document}
```